# How can I get deleted chats back?

Tags: ps4

I need my deleted conversations recovered.

Can someone help me? tell me How I get these back?

I have a PS4.

Answer (score 3):

Per [kenjara](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/72140/kenjara) comment:

> You cant. If you need it for legal reasons then Sony may be able to help you but I wouldn't count on it.